# R Connect to AWS Athena

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am attempting to connect to AWS Athena based upon what I have read online, but I am having issues.

**Steps taking**

- Update Java
- replace user/pass with accesskey/secretKey
- pass accesskey/secretKey with user/pass as well

Any ideas?

**Error Message:**

Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: AWS accessId/secretKey or AWS credentials provider must be provided

**System Information**

```
  sysname                           release                                       version 
  "Linux"                           "4.4.0-62-generic"      "#83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017" 
  nodename                          machine                                        login
 "ip-***-**-**-***"                 "x86_64"                                      "unknown" 
  user                              effective_user 
 "rstudio"                          "rstudio"
```

**Code https://www.r-bloggers.com/interacting-with-amazon-athena-from-r/**

```
library(RJDBC)

URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar'
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", fil, identifier.quote="'")

con <- jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(drv, 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/',
                                   s3_staging_dir="s3://mybucket",
                                   user=Sys.getenv("myuser"),
                                   password=Sys.getenv("mypassword"))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Athena JDBC driver is expecting your AWS Access Key Id as the `user`, and the Secret Key as the `password`:

```
accessKeyId <- "your access key id..."
secretKey <- "your secret key..."

jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(
  drv, 
  'jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443',
  s3_staging_dir="s3://mybucket",
  user=accessKeyId,
  password=secretKey
)
```

The R-bloggers article obtains those from environment variables using `Sys.getenv("ATHENA_USER")` and `Sys.getenv("ATHENA_PASSWORD")`, but that is optional.

---

**Updated**: Using a Credentials Provider with the Athena driver from R

@Sam is correct that a Credentials Provider is the best practice for handling AWS credentials.  I recommend the [DefaultCredentialsProviderChain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html), it covers several options for loading credentials from CLI profiles, environment variables, etc.

1. Download the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/), specifically the SDK jar from (`lib`) and a directory of third-party dependency jars (`third-party/lib`).
2. Add a bit of R code to add all the jar files to rJava's classpath

   ```
   # Load JAR Files
   library("rJava")

   .jinit()

   # Load AWS SDK jar
   .jaddClassPath("/path/to/aws-java-sdk-1.11.98/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.98.jar")

   # Add Third-Party JARs
   jarFilePaths <- dir("/path/to/aws-java-sdk-1.11.98/third-party/lib/", full.names=TRUE, pattern=".jar")
   for(i in 1:length(jarFilePaths)) {
       .jaddClassPath(jarFilePaths[i])
   }
   ```
3. Configure the Athena driver to load the credentials provider class by name

   ```
   athenaConn <- dbConnect(
     athenaDriver, 
     'jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443',
     s3_staging_dir="s3://mybucket",
     aws_credentials_provider_class="com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"
     )
   ```

Getting the classpath set up is key.  When `dbConnect` is executed, the Athena driver will attempt to load the named class from the JARs, and this will load all dependencies.  If the classpath does not include the SDK JAR, you will see errors like:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

And without the third-party JAR references, you may see errors like this:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Comment: Thanks, new to AWS and was scratching my head.

Comment: it's better to use IAM instance profile or roles instead of hard coding your AWS credentials in your code. Previously, you could use roles if you had only launched the instance with IAM roles, but, now, AWS has introduced a feature that roles can be attached to even RUNNING instances - but for now, you should do this via AWS CLI. good luck

Comment: @Sam, I agree that using a credentials provider is the best practice, if available.  I updated the answer to illustrate the alternative.  It wasn't quite as easy to do in R as I might like.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Where do you define "athenaDriver"?

Comment: @seapen, the variable `athenaDriver` is the same as `drv` from the last source paragraph in the original question.  It is the result of calling `JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", ...`